# Laravel Livewire File upload Return Null on Server but works on local

Tags: laravel, file-upload, null

Working perfect on local environment but on server it returns null.

This is livewire Controller code

```
        dd($this->photo); // this return null
        if($this->photo != null){
            Storage::delete($driverCarDetails->photo);
            $photo = $this->photo->store('drivers');
            $driverCarDetails->photo = $photo;
           
        }
```

This is livewire component code

```
        <label for="photo">Driver Photo:</label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="photo" wire:model="photo">
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you run ´php artisan storage:link´ on server?